# How to make my android application wait for isInteractive() method to return false efficiently?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-notifications, thread-sleep

In my android application I am firing predefined notifications at predefined times daily which seeks user's input. I am using `powerManager` class class & acquiring wake lock. I am able to do that but my requirement is that my notification **should wait** if the user is actively doing something with his/her device.

I have tried this by using `isInteractive()` method (code below) provided by the `powerManager` class and the OS sometimes throws ANR (Application not responding) and it sometimes skips the notification altogether.

I have created a new thread simply to make my app wait until the device is not being used and then I have called my notification firing section.

```
    Public class myClass extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private void checkPhoneUsage(Context context, int alarmId){
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20)
                                    while(pm.isInteractive())
                                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                                else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20)
                                    while (pm.isScreenOn())
                                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                                // Call the method which fires Notification.
                                // fireNotification(alarmId);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e){
                                Log.e(Tag,"Error during thread.sleep");
                            }
                        }
                    });
       }
    }
```

I tried using `SystemClock.wait(ms)` but again the problem repeats, also this fails because it should not be used on a UI Thread.

Comment: you can't just hold the main thread forever like taht.

Comment: @njzk2, Is there a way where I can pause the thread (& leave the system resources) and then return after sometime (say 10secs) and check if it is free or not?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your use case. Are you waiting until the user stops using their phone, and then fire a notification?

Comment: isn't that going to be extremely annoying?

Comment: @njzk2 Actually, I am trying to reduce the annoyance to the user. He/she may not want to receive a pop up notification (with vibration & my app launch) when they are using gmaps on roads or on a call with someone.

Comment: the user will never want to have you app launch and their phone vibrate unless they opened the app themselves. If you want to attract the user's attention, use a Notification.

Comment: In my application, I am requesting the users to report their medication and symptoms details at that very instance, which is why my application should launch rather than to fire a traditional notification. I have tried traditional notification system but it didn't help much as the user's often ignored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't. Look at the documentation for isInteractive:

> The system will send a screen on or screen off broadcast whenever the
>   interactive state of the device changes. For historical reasons, the
>   names of these broadcasts refer to the power state of the screen but
>   they are actually sent in response to changes in the overall
>   interactive state of the device, as described by this method.

Instead, use a broadcast for screen off.  Then do whatever code you want in that receiver.  Or if you need it to happen on the other thread, have that thread wait for a message sent from this receiver.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to bypass this problem.

Create a new Alarm Intent to fire notification 1 minute after finding out that the device is currently being active. Cancel the previous alarms.

Capture the alarm broadcast and re-check whether the user is interacting with the device or not. If he is not then proceed to my actual notification, which is to launch the app & setup new Alarm Intent at the predefined time. Otherwise repeat the previous step or creating the new Alarm Intent.

This way I am not holding up the system resources and I am able to achieve my objective, i.e. to fire notification and launch my app when the device is not being used by the user.